# MVC - set multiple ActionLink and TextBox properties inside the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, permissions, actionlink

I want to be able to set multiple form(html) objects (Textbox, ActionLink) to either visible = false or enabled = false based on a condition inside the controller.

In web forms I would do something like the code below. What is the best way to handle this in MVC inside the controller? Thanks!

```
switch (UserSession.AppUserAccessLevel)
            {
                case AccessLevel.FullAdmin:
                    txtLastName.Enabled = true;
                    lnkExportData.Visible = true;
                    btnSubmit.Enabled = true;               
                    break;
                case AccessLevel.Admin:
                    txtLastName.Enabled = true;
                    lnkExportData.Visible = false;
                    btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
                    break;
                case AccessLevel.ReadOnly:
                    lnkExportData.Visible = false;
                     btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing this in MVC you need to user Model and pass the Model to View through controller. Please find the example code below. You can loop through text boxes and set the property using Razor view.

```
Controller Action:

public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    //Sets your property
    string yourProperty = _db.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault();

    //Passing in "yourProperty" as the Model to the View
    return View(yourProperty);
}

//Alternativately you can bind the property to a Model that has multiple properties
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    YourModelClass model = new Model();
    model.Property = _db.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault();

    return View(model);
}

Within your View (Top of your View): (The name should match the name of the Controller Action - so YourAction.cshtml / YourAction.aspx)

//You need to firstly bind your Model to a type.
@Model string  //This is your first example above. It simply binds the Model to a string

@Model YourModelClass //This binds the Model (and all of its properties) to the passed in YourModelClass

Populating your Textboxes (Again - within your View)

//Now you can access and populate a textbox in the methods previously listed

@Html.TextBox("TextBoxName",Model) //If using a string for the Model
@Html.TextBox("TextBoxName",Model.YourProperty) //If using YourModelClass as the Model

or

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.YourProperty) //Again - using YourModelClass
```